# C++ server design - stuck handling packets

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, networking, design-patterns

I've been coding a OO server this weekend. There is problem I cannot overcome and have to ask for guidance. I added a lot of comments in the problematic part of code.
Quickly on design: `pacbuf` is an instance of `packet_buffer` which receives chunks of data and launches the lambda is the packet is complete (first 2 bytes of raw data is the size, so for example `0x06 0x00 0x01 0x22` is a valid packet of length 4). I am completly stuck on handling the parsed packet. I do not know how can I interpret an abstract response from `received_packet` (which is an abstract base class for any concrete packet). 
`client` instance represents one user (think of it as of session).
Below I attach the main handler with my comments and example of concrete packets.

```
void client::process_received_data(const char data[], size_t size)
{
    pacbuf.append_raw_data(data, size);
    pacbuf.retrieve_packets([this](unsigned short opcode, std::string&& data)
    {
        //encdec is a class responsible for decrypting valid packet
        encdec->decrypt_opcode(opcode); // here i got valid opcode (unique identifier of packet)
        encdec->decrypt(data); // here i got decrypted contents
        //packet factory returns a std::unique_ptr of abstraction -
        //  "class received_packet" which contains serialized contents
        auto packet = packet_factory->construct(opcode, std::forward<std::string>(data));
        if (packet == nullptr)
        {
            //when opcode is not associated with any implementation of received_packet
            logger::get_logger().log_error(login_ + " sent unknown packet");
            observer.request_close();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            //serialize the string with binary data into clean form
            //eventually throw std::underflow_error if not enough data was passed
            packet->parse_packet(); 
            //below is the a problem. I somehow need to get response if the packet
            //was a login request, or it was registration request,
            //or maybe something else - and every packet is handled in different way.
            //for example, login should update the "credentials" member of current client.
            //But the execute is virtual member of "received_packet" and so its an abstraction again
            //of course i can implement it in different ways but i got no idea how to pass it back to client
            //i need some mechanism that would take the "received_packet" and knew how to operate on "client"
            //so client could for example send back a packet with response to activity 
            //associated with concrete "received_packet"
            packet->execute();
        }
        catch (std::underflow_error& e)
        {
            logger::get_logger().log_error(login_ + ' ' + e.what());
            observer.request_close();
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Thats the abstract base

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "ByteSerializer.hpp"

class received_packet
{
public:

    virtual void parse_packet() = 0;
    virtual void execute() = 0; // execute should either know what to do or return something
    virtual ~received_packet() = default;

protected:

    received_packet(const std::string& rawData)
        : bs(rawData, 0) {}

    byte_serializer bs; // this is my own helper class (irrelevant)
};
```

And 2 example implementations.

```
#pragma once
#include "Packet.hpp"

class login_pass_packet : public received_packet
{
public:
    login_pass_packet(const std::string& rawData)
        :received_packet(rawData) {}

    virtual void parse_packet() override;
    virtual void execute() override;

private:

    char login[20];
    char pass[20];
};

void login_pass_packet::parse_packet()
{
    bs >> login >> pass;
}

void login_pass_packet::execute()
{
    //How can i let "client" know that its a login packet? Remember - execute is virtual    
}
```

And it this case i expect different kind of reponse

```
#pragma once
#include "Packet.hpp"

class key_register_packet : public received_packet
{
public:

    key_register_packet(const std::string& rawData)
        :received_packet(rawData) {}

    virtual void parse_packet() override;
    virtual void execute() override;

private:

    std::string key;
};

void key_register_packet::parse_packet()
{
    bs >> key;
}

void key_register_packet::execute()
{
    //and here, execute have to return key register request to client
}
```

So in the end - i am stuck handling the abstraction. After having concrete packet like login or key request i still see it is as `received_packet`.
Could someone point me in right direction?

Edit: The only thing that comes to my mind is to separate an interface from client which contains required functions and pass them via factory to the derived packet constuctor, so the execute could call the appropriate method on the client without revealing the rest of it. Is that a good idea?

Comment: You almost shouldn't have `parsePacket` be a virtual function.  You could have it be processed in the base class and then once you've figured out what kind of packet it is, make a new instance of a that specific packet type and put the pointer in private data, such as `received_packet* pointerToNewInstance`, using dynamic allocation  `new (pointerToNewInstance) key_register_packet(constructor parameters);`.  Then just have your base class packet Execute press Execute on its `pointerToNewInstance` derivative.  Just an idea.

Comment: Factory determines the derived class by the opcode. Derived class then knows how to parse the passed string for its own needs.

Comment: `std::forward<std::string>(data)` this seems not good, since data is `const char*`.

Comment: Look closely, data is std::string&& inside lambda. const char data[] is not visible here. I have to agree that i have to change the name tho